# Convert array of objects to an object

Tags: javascript

I have created this function, however is not quite right. I get this response from it:

```js
[
    {
        manufacturer: [
            'AUDI'
        ]
    },
    {
        body_colour: {
            'BLACK'
        }
    }
]
```

However what I want is:

```js
{
    manufacturer: [
        'AUDI'
    ],
    body_colour: {
        'BLACK'
    }
}
```

How can I get to this? This is what I have at the moment:

```js
checkForQueryString() {
    const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());

    let searchParams = Object.entries(params).map(([key, value]) => {
        return {
            [key]: value.split(',')
        }
    });
    return searchParams;
},
```

Query String: `?manufacturer=AUDI&body_colour=BLACK`

Comment: Note theres no point doing `Object.fromEntries` only to then use `Object.entries` in the very next line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reduce` not `map`

```js
const params = {
  manufacturer: "AUDI",
  body_colour: "BLACK"
}

let searchParams = Object.entries(params).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [key]: value.split(',')
  }
}, {});

console.log(searchParams)
```

Answer (score 1):

Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries()), Object.entries(params) are **not necessary**.

You can use a simple forEach function to achieve the desired result as from [MDN DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

```
function checkForQueryString() {

    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var result = {};
    searchParams.forEach(function(value, key) {
        result[key] = value.split(',');
    });
    return result;
}

console.log( checkForQueryString() );
```

When url is **http:example.com?manufacturer=audi,tesla&body_colour=black,white**

the output would be

```
{
    "manufacturer": [
        "audi",
        "tesla"
    ],
    "body_colour": [
        "black",
        "white"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumin you meant by your input:

```
body_colour: [
  'BLACK'
]
```

The answer can be:

```js
let myArray = [
  {
    manufacturer: ['AUDI']
  },
  {
    body_colour: ['BLACK']
  }
];
let newObj = Object.assign({}, ...myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Object.fromEntries` with split and map:

```js
const str = 'manufacturer=AUDI&body_colour=BLACK';

console.log(Object.fromEntries(str.split('&').map(o=>[o.split('=')[0],[o.split('=')[1]]])));
```